# sed can't read executable files when iterating in for loop

Tags: bash, sed, ls

In a terminal shell, I am trying to loop over a set of Python files and perform find and replace with sed, e.g.:

```sh
$ for f in `ls *.py`; do sed -i 's|foo|bar|g' $f; done;
```

However, for some of the files (in particular just those Python scripts that I've changed to be executable), it gives the error:

```
sed: can't read example_script.py: No such file or directory
```

Why might it not be working for executable files, but working for other files?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). Use `for f in *.py; do`.

Comment: Why use `ls` in this case at all?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the executable files are not being read by sed is because I have `ls` aliased to `ls --color=auto`. Therefore, the filenames returned by `ls` in the for loop are not just ascii strings with the filename, they also contain the colour information, e.g.,:

```
''$'\033''[01;32mexample_script.py'$'\033''[0m'
```

so sed can't find this weird file!

As pointed out in the comments, in this case there's actually no need to use `ls` to create my iterable list and I could instead do:

```sh
$ for f in *.py; do sed -i 's|foo|bar|g' "$f"; done;
```

or even without the for loop:

```sh
$ sed -i 's|foo|bar|g' *.py
```

*Original answer*: here's my original answer for posterity, kept here because it's what I did myself, before the help from the commenters.

The solution for me (given that this alias is set) is to instead run my for loop making sure to specify `ls --color=none`, i.e.,:

```sh
$ for f in `ls --color=none *.py`; do sed -i 's|foo|bar|g' $f; done;
```

Comment: The correct solution is to not use `ls` at all. You can use file globbing directly in a `for` statement: `for f in *.py ; do`.

Comment: I think that the premise of the question is flawed (why does this anti-pattern not work correctly?) but the only correct answer is to use a glob, so I would remove the middle part of your answer as it is only marginally less broken than the original attempt (try with `example script.py` which is a perfectly valid filename).

Comment: use `"$f"` to avoid issues due to file names... I'd rather use `sed -i 's|foo|bar|g' *.py` and avoid the loop altogether

Comment: Additionally, the aliasing problem only occurs in interactive sessions; in non-interactive session (such as when running a script), aliases are turned off by default.

Comment: No, it's **not alias expansion**. That only happens in interactive shells, not scripts (unless you explicitly turn it on, but nobody does that). Your error message is consistent, for example, with the existence of files with spaces, such as `my example_script.py`.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer that I was working on a terminal shell and not a script